# Is it possible to convert particular area of UIView into UIImage in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimage

I have already done to convert UIView into UIImage but i want that any particular section of the UIView be converted into UIImage so it is possible

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer drawInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: It's not exactly what you asked, but  you can try one thing, take image of you view then crop that particular area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([theImage CGImage], someRect);
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

You first would save the original `UIImage` from the `UIView` and then crop it with the above method. `someRect` is the rectangle area you want from the original `UIView`.

Comment: thanks but if i want to convert this croppedImage in png becuase i want to use this in pdf creation

Comment: take a look at this: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/05/download-an-image-and-save-it-as-png-or-jpeg-in-iphone-sdk/

Answer (score 0):

```
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([theImage CGImage], someRect);
CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
UIImage *croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSData *data= UIImagePNGRepresentation(croppedImage);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return img;
```

Comment: may write only this code or alos the above mine code also and how to show thig croped image in imageView